# How to compute ifft from fft?

Tags: c#, filter, signal-processing, fft

I've done a fft to get fundamental frequency in real time and to implement high and low pass filters.

Now I want to be able to record to a .wav file after I apply a filter.

First I'll have to invert the fft and that is my question.
What are the steps to do this?

I use the FFT defined in this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundCatcher.aspx).

Here is the code for it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SoundLog
{
    public class FourierTransform
    {
        static private int n, nu;

        static private int BitReverse(int j)
        {
            int j2;
            int j1 = j;
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= nu; i++)
            {
                j2 = j1 / 2;
                k = 2 * k + j1 - 2 * j2;
                j1 = j2;
            }
            return k;
        }

        static public double[] FFT(ref double[] x)
        {
            // Assume n is a power of 2
            n = x.Length;
            nu = (int)(Math.Log(n) / Math.Log(2));
            int n2 = n / 2;
            int nu1 = nu - 1;
            double[] xre = new double[n];
            double[] xim = new double[n];
            double[] magnitude = new double[n2];
            double[] decibel = new double[n2];
            double tr, ti, p, arg, c, s;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                xre[i] = x[i];
                xim[i] = 0.0f;
            }
            int k = 0;
            for (int l = 1; l <= nu; l++)
            {
                while (k < n)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++)
                    {
                        p = BitReverse(k >> nu1);
                        arg = 2 * (double)Math.PI * p / n;
                        c = (double)Math.Cos(arg);
                        s = (double)Math.Sin(arg);
                        tr = xre[k + n2] * c + xim[k + n2] * s;
                        ti = xim[k + n2] * c - xre[k + n2] * s;
                        xre[k + n2] = xre[k] - tr;
                        xim[k + n2] = xim[k] - ti;
                        xre[k] += tr;
                        xim[k] += ti;
                        k++;
                    }
                    k += n2;
                }
                k = 0;
                nu1--;
                n2 = n2 / 2;
            }
            k = 0;
            int r;
            while (k < n)
            {
                r = BitReverse(k);
                if (r > k)
                {
                    tr = xre[k];
                    ti = xim[k];
                    xre[k] = xre[r];
                    xim[k] = xim[r];
                    xre[r] = tr;
                    xim[r] = ti;
                }
                k++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
                //magnitude[i] = (float)(Math.Sqrt((xre[i] * xre[i]) + (xim[i] * xim[i])));
                decibel[i] = 10.0 * Math.Log10((float)(Math.Sqrt((xre[i] * xre[i]) + (xim[i] * xim[i]))));
            //return magnitude;
            return decibel;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many really good fft implementations around such as [FFTW](http://fftw.org) that I highly recommend using one. They come with ifft as well. Yours, as implemented, will be excruciatingly slow.

Comment: The velocity is not a problem at the moment.
I need to do it in c# and FFTW only has c++.

Can you tell me how can I convert the one that I posted plz?

Comment: There are two differences between the forward and inverse fts. The inverse needs to be scaled by 1/n and the exponential is negative. So, for the inverse ft (assuming I understand your implementation) change the sign of arg and multiply each point in the result by 1/n.

Comment: Also, you are using a complex fft for real data by setting all of the imaginaries to zero. This is mathematically sound but wasteful. Look at the Numerical Recipes web page (nr.com) for information on real valued ffts.

Comment: I'm passing from fft to ifft because I want to record to a .wav format.
After passing to ifft (that has the same length then the fft) do I need to make it bigger? And how do I put that data into a .wav? How do I make the .wav?